# how to enable base template on apphook'd page and use footer in static placeholder

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-cms

I've got an application hook to work as explained in the very basic sample of the [doc](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/05-apphooks.html). The application does its job, renders its own templates and does all navigation back and forth.

But I am facing 2 problems:

1. After putting the hooked application an a page via the advanced settings of the cms, I am no longer be able to edit the page over the frontend. If I navigate in /?edit mode to this particular page cms toolbar dismisses and the /?edit mode is taken away.
   How can I recover editing such an apphook'd page?
2. In the site's view mode (published apphook'd page) I have no styling and no `base.html` template stuff. So I miss the header menu coming from the base template and the footer which is generally added to each page by a static placeholder. Since I am not able to do frontend editing of the apphook'd page (as mentioned in paragraph 1), I am unable to embed the application into my well known page style.
   How can I get the intimate styling back for such an apphook'd page?

I am working with

- django 1.11.18
- djangocms 3.5.3
- python 3.7.2

Comment: Can you post the template(s) for the app which are used to render the page(s) where you're having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to go. Considerably following [this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/03-integrating_applications.html#improve-the-templates-for-polls) instructions did the trick. I was able to overload the particular template from within the apphook application.